Use another pair of SCL/SDA (ESP8266)
I want to access two sensors at the same time. Therefore I use the DFRobot_CCS811 and SdsDustSensor, but both use the pins for SCL/SCD (Pin 4 and 5). How can i use this?
// CCS811
#if _HAS_CO2_SENSOR_
#include "DFRobot_CCS811.h"
#endif

// SDS011
#if _HAS_DUST_SENSOR_
#include "SdsDustSensor.h"
#endif

#if _HAS_CO2_SENSOR_
DFRobot_CCS811 CCS811;
#endif

#if _HAS_DUST_SENSOR_
SdsDustSensor sds(rxPin, txPin);
#endif

#if _HAS_CO2_SENSOR_
  while (CCS811.begin() != 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize chip, please check the chip connection");
    delay(2000);
  }
  Serial.print("current configured parameter code is ");
  Serial.println(CCS811.getMeasurementMode());
  CCS811.setMeasurementMode(CCS811.eCycle_1s);
#endif

#if _HAS_DUST_SENSOR_
  sds.begin();
  Serial.println(sds.queryFirmwareVersion().toString());
  Serial.println(sds.setActiveReportingMode().toString());
  Serial.println(sds.setContinuousWorkingPeriod().toString());
#endif


I2C is a bus. you can wire multiple devices to it.
